# Distribution of a product

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $\Sigma$ be the covariance matrix of a multivariate normal distribution. 
We also know that, 
$$T \sim N(0,2/n) \hspace{1cm} i = j $$
$$T \sim N(0,1/n) \hspace{1cm} i \neq j $$

Is the product

$$\Sigma^{1/2}T \Sigma{1/2}$$

also multivariate normally distributed ? 
I guess yes but cant prove it.

Comment: I guess you mean $T$ is a random matrix with the same dimension as $\Sigma$, and its entries $T_{ij}$ follows the normal distribution stated by you. You try to express the entries in the product in terms of those $T_{ij}$. If $T_{ij}$ are jointly following a multivariate normal distribution (including the trivial case that they are independent), and you are able to express the entries inside the product as a linear combination of $T_{ij}$, then it also follows that all the entries are following a normal distribution.

Comment: Yes $T$ is random and $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix of a multivariate distributed vector $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ -- yes they are independent .. why is this case trivial ? sorry ... maybe i just cant see the wood for the trees.

Comment: so if we are able to express the product as a linear combination of $T_{ij}$ -- will we get any changes in our normal distribution ? so is $$\Sigma^{1/2} T \Sigma^{1/2} \sim T$$ or do we get changes in mean or variance?